# sending data between php and c

Tags: php, c, json

I would like to send data from a php script to a compiled c program on my server, and use the data output from the c program within the php script.

1. How do I go about doing this (Links please)
2. What is the best way to encode the data so that it is easily parsed in c
   -possible c libraries that unpack and pack json data
3. Is this the best route if the data is to require processing intensive operations?

Note, the project is to use the LAMP stack.

Comment: stdin/stdout, pipes, files, IPC, local-/network-domain sockets. You've got MANY choices for communications.

Comment: JSON, XML and SOAP???? SSH protocol to keep it safe??

Comment: You can use Apache Thrift over a local socket: http://thrift.apache.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the more I think about it, [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) seems to fit the bill here. You set up a service contract and Thrift will generate the interop code for you between PHP and C

> What is the best way to encode the data so that it is easily parsed in c -possible c libraries that unpack and pack json data

This is handled for you.

> Is this the best route if the data is to require processing intensive operations?

While vague, because the Thrift service is behind an abstracted service and supports non-blocking requests and thread-pooled servers and such, it can scale up pretty well if you implement your services correctly.